# Count all rows by status and day

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.4

I want to use this table to store tickets in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE TICKET(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 TITLE TEXT,
 STATUS INTEGER,
 LAST_UPDATED DATE,
 CREATED DATE
)
;
```

I use column 'status' to set different status(1, 2, 3, 4). How I can count all tickets by status and day with one SQL query?

I would like to get the final result for example like simple array of numbers:

```
32 31 23 42 9.11.215
31 21 13 22 10.11.215
3 3 2 43 11.11.215
```

Comment: Please explain better your output

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but how in the world do you have 879 questions, 21 gold badges, 103 silver, 211 bronze, yet only 47 reputation...?

Comment: I want to get this ouput because I will put it into Java object and display it into BarChart.

Comment: @Siyual I post a lot of bounty questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can doing it with conditional aggregation, which will unite separate rows into 1 aggregated row :

```
SELECT t.created,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = '1' THEN 1 END) as cnt_status1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = '2' THEN 1 END) as cnt_status2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = '3' THEN 1 END) as cnt_status3,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = '4' THEN 1 END) as cnt_status4
FROM ticket t
GROUP BY t.created
```

Comment: I get `ERROR:  column t.created_date does not exist`. I have column `created` not `created_date`

Comment: Mixed it up, why didn't you just change it? Anyway it's fixed @PeterPenzov

Comment: Now I get `ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer
LINE 2:        COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = 1 THEN 1 END) as cnt_statu...`

Comment: That's becuase `status` is a string, which is something you should have mentioned! Should work now as long as you don't have any more surprises:) @PeterPenzov